# Gatsby Build doesn't generate html for non-page components

Tags: gatsby, server-side-rendering, static-site

I have an page in index.js in gatsby with following structure:

```
export default () => {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <h1>Hello World</h1>
    </Layout>
  );
};
```

When I run `gatsby build` it generates a index.html in public. When public folder is served it all works well.

My problem is that the generated html doesn't have the content which is part of `Layout`. It generates something similar to following:

```
<html>
<head>
.
.
.
</head>
<body>
<div id="___gatsby"><h1>Hello World</h1></div>
// Some scripts
</body>
</html>
```

Rest of the content is basically generates by client (In this case browser). Content of the page is already rendered, and non-page components are rendered on client.

So, even when I run "Fetch as Google", I get above HTML. Wouldn't Google index above content and will miss the other content which is part of Layout.

What's the point of generating static pages? Or Is there a different way to generate?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was when you use responsive based classes like https://material-ui.com/components/hidden/

Gatsby won't include them as part of html as it's not possible.